# Is it possible to get City from Longitude/Latitude?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have heard that SQL Server now supports Geography like things. Is it possible to get City from Longitude/Latitude? I have search a lot but could not find any?

Comment: dont know about sql server, but probably using google maps api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to load some data with city locations - [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/)(you might want `cities15000.zip`) or [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/)(Populated places) might be good places to start.

```
CREATE TABLE cities ( 
  name VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY,
  location GEOGRAPHY, 
);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX idx_cities_location ON cities(location);

INSERT INTO cities (name, location) VALUES
  ('Auckland', geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(174.7833 -36.85)', 4326)),
  ('London', geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-0.1062 51.5171)', 4326))
;
```

- Note the order of all coordinates is `(Longitude Latitude)`
- Spatial indexes make it fast.
- the 4326 is the coordinate system code for basic Longitude/Latitude.

Then to find the closest city to a given location you want a query like:

```
DECLARE @g geography = 'POINT(103.75 1.3667)';
SELECT TOP(1) name FROM cities
WHERE location.STDistance(@g) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY location.STDistance(@g);
```

More examples in the SQL Server docs:

- [Create, Construct, and Query geography Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895266.aspx)
- [Query Spatial Data for Nearest Neighbor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929109.aspx)

Comment: Is reverse-geocoding just nearest neighbor search? Could I be closer to one city, but by (alt) definition be in another? How likely is this if true? Edit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13832418/1464716 answers that. Any implementations out there considering city borders?

Comment: @nous if you're in B, you're unlikely to be closest to A... although rivers and harbours can mess that up sometimes. The example above treats cities as points. If you want to work with boundaries the above should still work (with (Multi)Polygon geometries) - `STDistance()` will return 0 if the query point is inside a specific city polygon, so it will sort first.

Comment: using cities15000.zip will get only normal location address what can i do to get current address (exact address) ?

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you're describing is called "Reverse-Geocoding" - taking a lat/lng coordinate, and returning the name of the nearest place to that location. (Geocoding is the opposite - providing a placename in order to retrieve the associated lat/lng coordinates).

You can certainly build a reverse-geocoding service that uses SQL Server as the backend database, but there's nothing built-in to provide such functionality.

If you simply want to reverse-geocode a set of existing data, rather than create this functionality in SQL Server, you might find it easier to use an existing webservice. For example, the geonames findNearbyPlaceName has a REST interface that you access via the following URL template:

http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=52.62&lng=1.28&username=demo

This example returns information about the nearest known entity to the requested lat/lng coordinates (52.62,1.28) from the geonames database, as follows:

```
<geonames>
  <geoname>
    <toponymName>Norwich</toponymName>
    <name>Norwich</name>
    <lat>52.62783</lat>
    <lng>1.29834</lng>
    <geonameId>2641181</geonameId>
    <countryCode>GB</countryCode>
    <countryName>United Kingdom</countryName>
    <fcl>P</fcl>
    <fcode>PPLA2</fcode>
    <distance>1.51318</distance>
  </geoname>
</geonames>
```

Answer (score 2):

For spatial functions, you'll need SQL 2008 or newer.

Number one thing to do is get the book / ebook: Beginning Spatial with SQL Server by Alastair Aitchison. He has a version for SQL 2008 and 2012. He is one of the top gurus out there. Another is 'Spatial Dave'. Disclosure: no, I don't get a dime recommending Alistair's books. I work for GreatData.com and have used the 2008 book when I knew very little about SQL and nothing about mapping and have been able to get pretty proficient in a short time because the book is so good.

Next, you'll need to load in City boundaries. These are in ESRI Shapefile format and you can find them for free at NationalAtlas.gov (a great source for free mapping files).

You need to understand that only larger cities have map boundary files. With a boundary, you can use STIntersects() or other methods to determine if the latitude / longitude coordinate that you have falls within the city limits.

For smaller cities and towns, you'll only get a lat/long point. You can use 'nearest neighbor' logic (also in the book) to determine the closest city or town, but will not be able to determine if it is within the town limits or not.